# Is there an analogous way to create an array without its prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there something analogous to `Object.create(null)`, where the object has no prototype, for an `Array`?

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.__proto__ = null;
```

Comment: I'm interested why you might need this?

Comment: An array without its prototype would not behave like an array. It would be basically be an empty object (the prototype is what makes that object an array)

Comment: @slebetman, are you sure it will be empty `Object`? because `console.log` shows that it still `Array`: `var a = []; a.__proto__ = null; Array.prototype.push.call(a, 123); console.log(a);` will show `[123]`, not `{'123'}`.

Comment: @slebetman: No, the special `.length` property and the internal [[Class]] are what makes an array an array.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question: `a.__proto__ = null` ??

Comment: @AlexD, I'm learning JavaScript and developing concept of something like JSONable object, which has only number, string, array without prototype, object without prototype, I need this to assert that config is a proper JSONable object

Comment: @happy_marmoset: Not sure what you mean by "JSONable". JSON converts from and to objects and arrays *with* their standard prototypes.

Comment: @happy_marmoset: You seem to be asking this for academic purposes only, I hope? If so, the answer is "no there is nothing", if not, the answer should be "don't do that"

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing like `Array.create` that creates arrays without a prototype. However, `__proto__` is despised (it's legacy only), the proper way would be

```
var someWeirdArray = Object.setPrototypeOf([], null);
```

which also has the advantage of being a single expression.

---

And just a word of caution (that you hopefully don't need): ***Don't do this!*** There's no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for future viewers, if you want to have an array without the weight associated with the prototype, just use `Object.create(null)` and key it with numbers.

```
const myEmptyObj = Object.create(null)

myEmptyObj[0] = 'someStuff'
myEmptyObj[1] = 'someOtherStuff'
```

you might even be able to convince array methods to work on it. I haven't tried this but:

```
const arrMap = (fn, arr) => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn)
```

where `arr` is the object in question and `fn` is your map function...